# Decreasing runtime of Fortran program with compiling and linking flags in GNU

Tags: optimization, fortran, runtime, gnu, flags

My problem is related to runtime of a .exe app. I've been given a very large code (which I know is bug free) but it takes too much time to run. I have compiled it with GNU and I'm not able to use the parallel programming neither due to my computer having only two processors.

The problem is tied to a single subroutine of 2000 lines. I have notice that it is mainly made up of loops, where I think there the problem is. Also it is called like 20000 times by the main program.

First I used the -O flags (the best runtime was with -Ofast). After that, I tried to improve the loops performance with -fforce-addr, but no measurable acceleration happened. Lately I am using other flags like -mtune to create a code optimized for the local machine.

Here are my main tests and results:

- Original program (31s)

`COMPOPTS= -pthread -finline-functions -fbacktrace -fzero-initialized-in-bss -fno-automatic -frecord-marker=4 LINKOPTS= -l unlimit -s unlimited`

- Using -Ofast (25s)

`COMPOPTS= -pthread -finline-functions -fbacktrace -fzero-initialized-in-bss -fno-automatic -frecord-marker=4 -cpp LINKOPTS= -l unlimit -s unlimited`

- Last situation (24s)

`COMPOPTS= -mtune=native -pthread -finline-functions -fbacktrace -fzero-initialized-in-bss -fno-automatic -frecord-marker=4 -cpp -fforce-addr -fschedule-insns2 -ffp-contract=off LINKOPTS=-l ulimit -s unlimited`

I have a .exe version compiled with Intel and it’s runtime is 7s. I know Intel usually is like a 20-40% faster than GNU, so I think there is some room for improvement.

Comment: Hi avier_carrero and welcome to SO, Can you provide more technical details and maybe trace data to help better understand the issue

Comment: Please take the welcome [tour] and read [ask]. We can only help you if you give us some *specific* information. There are actually many articles, even books, about optimization and parallelization. We need to know the details of your code, your runtime test results and the flags you tried. Optimization is hard and it cannot be done without seeing the code and testing it.

Comment: What you are looking for is gprof.  This is the GNU profiler.  With gfortran add the -pg option and execute the program.  It should generate a *.gmon file with profiling information to tell you where the bottlenecks are in the program.

Comment: How is the intel executable compiled? Does it use multiple threads? If yes, then how?

Comment: I do not have any information about the Intel version compilation. I have written to the developer in order to get more information.